# AWS to Internal LAN Connectivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, local-area-network, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC on AWS I would like to have it connect via secure connection to my internal LAN which is in the firewall. I have few questions which are from the clients.

1. How do I connect the VPC to Internal LAN, considering the VPC all nodes are linux machine ( either ubuntu® or RedHat® ).
2. How do I insure that every request generated from VPC nodes are from the VPC nodes only, is there a way to have some ssl certificate or any other means?
3. Client was suggesting a reverse proxy on a DMZ server the DMZ would be available to both the VPC and Internal LAN.

This question is similar to [this question in SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/125646/how-to-connect-public-web-server-to-internal-lan), however this is for Linux and not for windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AWS VIRTUAL PRIVATE GATEWAYS` for connecting local infrastructure to AWS Infrastructure with OpenVPN. 
[More information about configuration](http://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/AWS/aws-VPN-Connections-Virtual-Private-Gateways.php)

Answer (score 0):

To
1. Like Rakesh C states you can use the AWS VPN Gateway http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html

For 2 and 3:
For a more detailed answer you need to provide more information.
What is your usecase?
What needs do you want to satisfy?